# Microsoft Excel cannot access the file “…”. There are several possible reasons Windows Server 2008 R2 with Microsoft Office 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

In my development server, this code is working fine but after hosting into IIS, I am getting this error, and whatever the solution I got on Google,

[image]

I tried that all, but nothing worked for me.

please help me since my production is blocked because of this.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So the user that IIS is hosting your web application under have access to U: and the rest of the path? Write access if saving, read access if loading?

Comment: - are you sure that file exists ?
- are you sure that IIS can read from that location ?

Comment: You need to detail exactly what you've looked at and tried because right now, if you've tried **all** possible solutions to this, then clearly you have an unsolvable problem.

Comment: Have you tried looking into the *correct* folder? Or simply *not* using Excel on the server? What would you do if *two* people tried to access the same page? Or if you left one instance running and tried to use another one to load the *same* file?

Comment: *Don't* use the obsolete `xls` format. Use the `xlsx` format introduced **10** years ago and a library like EPPlus to read/write xlsx files *without* requiring Excel on the server.

Comment: write more about you error.

Answer (score 0):

You can set security for your folder. I hope it will help you.

[image]